# Inserting data from database into spinner in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-spinner

Can somebody teach me how to fetch the data from the SQLite database and place all the information gathered from the database into the Spinner. For example, I have a tblState in my db and I need to get all the State_name from the database and fetch it to the spinner. How will I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following is an example of Android with sqlite. It is very useful for beginner. Example contains ListActivity instead if Spinner. Just learn the example properly and you can make changes according your requirements.

```
public class CRUDonDB extends ListActivity {

    private final String SAMPLE_DB_NAME = "myFriendsDb";
    private final String SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME = "friends";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = null;

        try {
            sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(SAMPLE_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

            sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR," +
                    " Country VARCHAR, Age INT(3));");

            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " Values ('Makam','Sai Geetha','India',25);");
            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " Values ('Chittur','Raman','India',25);");
            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " Values ('Solutions','Collabera','India',20);");

            Cursor c = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName, Age FROM " +
                    SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME +
                    " where Age > 10 LIMIT 5", null);

            if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
                        int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
                        results.add("" + firstName + ",Age: " + age);
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                } 
            }

            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));

        } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
        } finally {
            if (sampleDB != null) 
                sampleDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME);
                sampleDB.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Also have a look at this [Spinner Example](http://www.mydoople.com/android-spinner-example).

Comment: @MaciejGórski, Yes agree, but as I said this is very beginner's example.